# How do I configure ADFS 3.0 Relying Party Trust and update my AngularJS & ASP.NET Web API applications to use ADFS with my company’s Active Directory?

Tags: angularjs, adfs

I am a beginner with `ADFS` and do not know where to begin. I have an `AngularJS` `1.4.9` application which makes `Ajax` calls to an `ASP.NET Web API 2.2` service.

Both applications are hosted within `IIS` under the same site and both use `Windows Authentication` on my company’s intranet.  I’d like to modify them to use `ADFS` so that these applications can be accessed from the internet without a `VPN`.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off looking into using the web application proxy (WAP)functionality for now. WAP allows publishing internal resources and making them internet accessible.

Once you get AD FS and WAP deployed, see step 3 in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280943.aspx#BKMK_3

You can then look to slowly updating your applications to use federated authentication with AD FS.